# integration by mid point method

Tags: integration

I want to integrate S1,S2,S3,S4 (functions of s and t), one by one using mid point method by for loop. but I do not know how to integrate.because in mid point method first i need a function and then apply the method. this will make a matrix.

```
clear all
clc
syms r s t 
a=-1;
b=1;
n=10;
h=(b-a)/(n-1);
S1(1)=(1/4)*(1-s)*(1-t);S1(2)=(1/4)*(1-s)*(1-t);
S1(3)=(1/4)*(1-s)*(1-t);S1(4)=(1/4)*(1-s)*(1-t);
s=a:h:b; t=a:h:b;
for i=1:2
  for j=1:length(s)-1
    for k=1:length(t)-1
      K(1,i)=S(i)^2;  
      (mid point method) 
    end
  end
end
```

how we can integrate using for loop and mid point or quadrature rule.
please help.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange.com! You may improve your post by [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/448487) in order to make it clearer.

Comment: You can use http://hostmath.com to format MathJax easily.

Comment: Programming questions are more welcome on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), even if they are about MATLAB.